# Method turns objects values into NaN. I guess it has something to do with 'this' keyword

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a timer in javascript for a little game using classes. For some reason function *start()* doesn't work and it's execution turns timer's values (s and cs) into *NaN*. Is there something wrong with *this* keyword?

```
class Timer
    {
        constructor()
        {
            this.s = 0;
            this.cs = 0;
        }

        start()
        {
            this.timerID = setInterval(function()
            {
                this.cs++;
                if (this.cs >= 100)
                    {
                        this.s++;
                        this.cs = this.cs % 100;
                    }}, 
                    10);
            }

        stop()
        {
            clearInterval(this.timerID);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The value of `this` in your timer callback won't be the value it was in the context where the timer was established.

Comment: Yup, use an arrow function instead

Comment: Declare the `this` in a variable like `var _this = this;` and then use it.  The setInterval has a different scope so the `this` points to something different.

Comment: `var that = this;` is also quite conventional.